# Prevent passbooks group together

Tags: ios, wallet, passkit

My passbooks are user's store cards, they have same certificate (same pass type identification) and category as discuss in this [link](http://support.passdock.com/discussions/questions/47-grouping-of-passes), but I don't want them to group together since they are for many different stores or business. Any way to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `storecard` passes, the only way to prevent grouping is to use a different certificate.  `coupon`, `storecard` and `generic` passes with the same `passTypeIdentifier` will always be grouped together.

For `eventTicket` and `boardingPass` types, you can use a `groupingIdentifier` key to separate passes with the same `passTypeIdentifier` into different groups.

> `groupingIdentifier` |
>   `string` |
>   *Optional for event tickets and boarding passes; otherwise not allowed. Identifier used to group related passes. If a grouping identifier is specified, passes with the same style, pass type identifier, and grouping identifier are displayed as a group. Otherwise, passes are grouped automatically.
>   Use this to group passes that are tightly related, such as the boarding passes for different connections of the same trip.
>   Available in iOS 7.0.*

[PassKit Package Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW1)